# TortoiseHG: add all files in directory tree

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg

How do I add all files in a direcory tree to my repository. I can do it file by file but it seems as not the most efficient solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do the commit, you can enter filter text at the top of the commit dialog, just enter the specific directory you want to add, and the other files will be filtered, after that, check all, and commit

Answer (score 0):

I think [Create Repository Here](http://tortoisehg.bitbucket.io/manual/2.0/quick.html#initialize-the-repository) under `TortoiseHg` in the Context Menu of the folder in Windows Explorer is what you are looking for.

Comment: Bu this is for creating a repository. I just want to add stuff to an existing repository.

Comment: Then [Add Files](http://tortoisehg.bitbucket.org/manual/2.0/quick.html#add-files) further below is what you are looking for

Comment: @Patrick: Have you been able to solve the problem? If it is so, I suggest that you mark smooth reggae's answer as accepted.

Comment: Imwas really bussy and not working wit tortoise. Ill give it a try tonight, but from what I remember it did only allowed me to add 1 file and not a directory structure.